# Unable to compile after adding dependency to POM.xml

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have an existing project and i need to add Spring Security and Spring Security Test.

I can't figure out how to add it with IntelliJ.

I know how to do this when creating a new project and I have the PlugIn installed.

Please help me find out how to add it to an existing project

When I add the dependencies manually to the POM.xml, I get the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method defaultSecurityFilterChain in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:59290', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.exaple.pma</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectmanagement</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectmanagement</name>
    <description>projectmanagement</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UPDATE - 1/18/2022
when I run

```
 mvnw spring-boot:run
```

from Terminal on Windows, it works. When i click the DEBUG icon in IntelliJ, i get this exception. How do I fix this? Running from Terminal to debug once is fine but the point of using an IDE diminishes if I need to run the project from Terminal.

Comment: It's not a dependency issue but your Spring context is not defined correctly.

Comment: How do I define my Spring Context

Comment: @GaëlJ can you help?

Comment: There is related feature quest on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148776

Answer (score 0):

To add new dependency:

- First visit https://mvnrepository.com/ and search the dependency you want to add. Then copy that dependency.
- Now go to IntelliJ and open pom.xml and add your copied dependency here.[image]

Comment: I tried this but the application won't compile. It says "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity' in your configuration."

Is there a way to add it using the GUI?

Comment: This error is not related to pom.

Comment: Thank you but do you know how to resolve the problem?